# Use PYTHONSTARTUP to interactively test a python file in the interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to establish a standard script file that is imported into python at startup using the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable. Additionally, I want to be able to conveniently reload the same script file after modifying it in an external editor, to test its behavior after the modification.
I created a ~/.pythonrc.py file and set it as PYTHONSTARTUP:

```
import os
import imp

def load_wb():
    _cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),'Skripte'))
    import workbench
    imp.reload(workbench)
    os.chdir(_cwd)

load_wb()
```

This is my very minimal script file for the start:

```
def dull_function():
    print('Not doing much...')

print('Workbench loaded.')
```

When I launch Python 3.1.2, .pythonrc is successfully executed and the workbench.py is imported, but dull_function does not appear in the global namespace or in a local one. What do I have to do differently?

Comment: Have you tried `workbench.dull_function`?

Comment: workbench.dull_functuion yields a NameError. This is not surprising, as neither workbench nor dull_function appear in the namespace listed by dir() after the imports. imp.reload(workbench) returns a module object. Is there a way to intergrate this object manually into the global namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `import` statement outside the function. You're basically importing the `workbench` module into the function scope, not the global scope (Try calling `workbench.dull_function` from inside `load_wb` to see for yourself).

In other words, change your code to:

```
import os
import imp
import workbench

def load_wb():
    _cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'), 'Skripte'))
    imp.reload(workbench)
    os.chdir(_cwd)

load_wb()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really solving your immediate problem but... You might appreciate using iPython shell for testing in that case. Using the autoimport functionality, you can mark a module for (re)loading on each executed line if needed.

That means you can `%aimport workbench` and then every time you run `some_function_Im_testing()`, `workbench` will be reloaded if it changed. Just add the autoimport line into the configuration file for ipython and you're done.